# Getting Authentication Form Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the following code in Global.asax.cs (which I believe is an MVC conventional name)

```
   Configuration conn = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("");
   AuthenticationSection section = (AuthenticationSection)conn.SectionGroups.Get("system.web").Sections.Get("authentication");
   Application["Expire"] = System.Convert.ToInt64(section.Forms.Timeout.TotalMinutes);
```

to grab the timeout from the following form in Web.Config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".FooAuth" path="/" protection="All" requireSSL="false" loginUrl="~/Member/Login" timeout="30" />
 </authentication>
```

Application["Expire"] always gets 30, despite any changes to the timeout variable. I'm thinking that I must be changing the wrong variable somewhere. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.Timeout`

Comment: Could you explain your comment further?

Comment: You don't really have to use the code from the past, where the timeout was not directly available and we had to manually read it as shown above in your snippet. For years, the timeout is directly available as shown in mine.

Comment: Well, a lot of wasted work on my part. Thanks for the help!